# Adaptive Card to send message to the end user by command / Bot Framework SDK - JavaScript - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

For MS Teams chatbot, by adaptive cards, I want the bot to send text message to the client when the client chooses the respective command. What İs want is opposite of Action.Submit - I want user to receive message when the button is clicked.

I try to optimize Action.OpenUrl and Action.Submit but results weren't satisfying.